# jQuery: Form slideDown() at load

Tags: jquery

How can I have my form load with a `slideDown()` effect rather than normal rendering?

Also, how do I know when a particular div or element has been loaded?

Comment: Could you be bothered to read the [documentation on the `.slideDown()` effect](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)?

Comment: I have already tried, that is why I am posting here. I thought you would have figured that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible option is:

```
$.post('/url-having-your-form/',{data:someDataHere},function(response){
   $('#your-destination-element-that-needs-the-form').html(response).slideDown('slow',function(){
      // this code will be executed after the slideDown has finished
   });
},'html');
```

Assuming that your page hasn't already got the form, use the above (modifying where required) and if it has already got the form, then you can you try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#your-destination-element').css({display:'none'}).slideDown();
});
```

What behaviour are you currently seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your form within a div, `<div id='mydiv'></div>`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydiv').hide();
    $('#mydiv').slideDown('slow',function(){
      //here write something, it will be executed when slidedown is complete
      alert('div loaded');
    })
});
```

You can also do it without wrapping in div, but semantic matters.

Comment: Not needed, `<form>` can be used as well

Comment: Added additional info before your comment :)

Comment: Sorry still can't see any reason to have it wrapped with `<div>` - form is block level element as well..

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to have the form initially hidden (adding `style="display: none;"` to it) then have it slide down when document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").slideDown("slow");
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/V2hmR/).

Regarding your other question (when a particular div or element has been loaded) it's possible only for images, ordinary DOM elements like `<div>` do not trigger any event when they finish loading, you can only handle the global `onload` of the window/document itself.

Comment: The form does slide down, but after sliding completely down, it goes up by 5pixel. Its probably not noticeable but I was just wondering is this because of padding in my css?

Comment: Tried adding padding to the jsFiddle sample but it didn't cause any problem like you describe. Can you reproduce that in the jsFiddle somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply slide down the element you want, at the moment the page has been complete loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('elementYouWant').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: add `alert('test');` inside to see if jQuery has been loaded at all.
Please say the environment you run this, platform, etc. Or give some more info by editing your question.

Comment: its slideDown() not SlideDown()